# Smart Totaling in Reports

Tags: custom-reports

> How to avoid **smart totaling** feature in Salesforce Reports?Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: When you create a Dashboard table component based on Report  because Smart Totaling works for Reports, but NOT for Dashboards.

Comment: Thanks samir , but we need to summaries the report and can not use table dashboard component.